# Settext not called while it is called before a FOR loop

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, button

Whenever I am clicking on a option item, the for loop will go first, and after the for loop is finished, the button text will be set. Why is it set AFTER the for loop is done, when it's fired BEFORE the for loop?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.refresh) {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setText("Running");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "We are currently running this function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("For is running" + i);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                //Don't do shit :)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case its returning `true` after the loop executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you stop the UI thread within the loop. It will set the text st the button object level, but is stopped before this can be reflected to the user interface. If you want to execute some code which takes a percievable amount of time, you should always use a background activity. For examples see for example "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html".

Comment: Hi, please see my edit. Removed sleep, as it was just to delay things a bit so you could actually see that the for loop takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly, method public **boolean** onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) waits until you send back a boolean value. I will not show your button till you return true.

2) Second, it's very bad idea sleep() on UI thread. Instead try runOnUlThred():

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.refresh) 
    {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setText("Running");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "We are currently running this function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
        public void run() 
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("For is running" + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                //Don't do shit :)
            }
        }
        }
        }
    return true;
    }
    else return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Hi, please see my edit. Removed sleep, as it was just to delay things a bit so you could actually see that the for loop takes some time.